# Nodejs user registration form error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am making a dummy learning project using MEAN stack. I am now stuck at a problem.

index.controller.js

```
var User = require("../models/user");
controller.registerUser = function(req,res){    
User.find({
   'email' :  req.body.email
},  function(err, user){
    console.log(req.body.email);
    console.log(user);
    if(user){
        res.send("User already exist");            
    }else{
        var userModel = new User();
        userModel.email = req.body.email.toLowerCase();
        userModel.password = userModel.generateHash(req.body.password);                
        userModel.save(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("Error Occurred");
            } else {
                res.send("User Created");
            }
        });            
    }
});    

};
module.exports = controller;
```

Each time I am getting the response

> `"User already exist"`

Whereas there are no users in my collection. What I have done wrong?

Comment: what does `console.log(user);`  prints

Comment: it prints [ ] this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` will return an Array user, so to you have make the condition, whether the user is null `[]` or not,

such as

```
if (user.length > 0) {
   res.send("User already exist");
} else {
// do your stuffs
}
```

---

If you are searching for the one user it's better to use **`findOne`**, **`findOne`** returns a single document not array

---

If the user isn't in the database it returns the null

**`Use findOne instead of find`**

```
   var User = require("../models/user");
    controller.registerUser = function(req,res){    
    User.findOne({                
       'email' :  req.body.email
    },  function(err, user){
        console.log(req.body.email);
        console.log(user);
        if(user){
            res.send("User already exist");            
        }else{
            var userModel = new User();
            userModel.email = req.body.email.toLowerCase();
            userModel.password = userModel.generateHash(req.body.password);                
            userModel.save(function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send("Error Occurred");
                } else {
                    res.send("User Created");
                }
            });            
        }
    });    

    };
    module.exports = controller;
```

Answer (score 0):

`User.find` returns an array in your case an empty array `[]`.

`if` on empty array **returns true**.

If you have method `User.findOne` use that when search for single record

```js
var users = [];
if (users)
  console.log('Check1: User found');
else
  console.log('Check1: User not found');

// Use below code
if (users && users.length > 0)
  console.log('Check2: User found');
else
  console.log('Check2: User not found');
```